# What could be an optimized way of deleting keys from an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nsmutablearray

I had a use case to remove multiple keys from an JSON object or an array of objects.Below is my code.If anyone has more optimized approach for this then suggest.

```
       exports.removeAttributes = function (arrayOfAttributesToRemove, object, callback) {
    let checkForRemoveOrRetain = true;
    removeORRetain(arrayOfAttributesToRemove, object, checkForRemoveOrRetain, (err, object) => {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            callback( object);
        }
    });
};
exports.retainAttributes = function (arrayOfAttributesToRetain, object, callback) {
    let checkForRemoveOrRetain = false;
    removeORRetain(arrayOfAttributesToRemove, object, checkForRemoveOrRetain, (err, object) => {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            callback(object);
        }
    });
}

    let removeORRetain = function (arrayOfAttributesToRemove, object, checkForRemoveOrRetain, callback) {
    if (Array.isArray(object)) {
        for (let i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
            for (let key in object[i]) {
                if (arrayOfAttributesToRemove.includes(key) === checkForRemoveOrRetain) {
                    delete object[i][key];
                }
            }
        }
        callback(object);
    } else {
        for (let key in object) {
            if (arrayOfAttributesToRemove.includes(key) === checkForRemoveOrRetain) {
                delete object[key];
            }
        }
        callback( object);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with lodash very easily.

```
const _ = require('lodash');

exports.removeAttributes = function (arrayOfAttributesToRemove, object, callback) {
   // check for errors etc. Then

   // Create an array of objects if not already.
   const arr = _.concat([], object);
   // call callback with new arr with omitted properties using _.map and _.omit
   callback(null, _.map(arr, e => _.omit(e, arrayOfAttributesToRemove)));
};
```

If you want to retain properties then use `_.pick`